# How to deal with recursion in toString Java method?

Tags: java, recursion, tostring

My program is structured as follows: a class that represents an *atomic concept* which is essentially a String and another class that is made of a list of general concepts. Both classes extends the class Concept that is an abstract class, this means that in the list I could have both atomic concepts and intersection of concepts arbitrary nested.
Each concept, atomic or composed, is printed out by toString method.
Roughly speaking, this is based on this context-free grammar:

```
C : atom | (C and)+ C
```

Where *C* is the abstract class Concept, *atom* is AtomicConcept and *(C and)+ C* is Intersection.

This is the AtomicConcept class:

```
public class AtomicConcept extends Concept{

private String atomicConceptName;

public AtomicConcept(String c) {
    this.atomicConceptName = c;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return atomicConceptName;
   }
```

}

This is che ConceptIntersection class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ConceptIntersection extends Concept{

private List<Concept> list;

public ConceptIntersection(List<Concept> l) throws Exception {
    if(l.size()>1)
    {
        this.list = l;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Intersection needs at least two concepts!");
    }
   }

public String toString()
{
    return Utils.conceptIntersection + Utils.lparen + Utils.splitConcepts(list) + Utils.rparen;

}

}
```

As you can see in toString function, I also created a method called *splitConcepts* that takes in input a list of general concepts and returns one string made of each concept separated by comma.

```
public static String splitConcepts(List<Concept> list)
{
    String result = "";
    for (Concept item : list) {
        System.out.println(item);
        result += item.toString() + comma;

    }
    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Where is the problem?
I have trouble with this function because when I call a nested intersection in another one, **this function never ends**!

One example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DLRException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AtomicConcept atom = new AtomicConcept("one");
    AtomicConcept at = new AtomicConcept("two");
    List<Concept> list = new LinkedList<Concept>();
    list.add(at);
    list.add(atom);
    DLRConceptIntersection intersection = new DLRConceptIntersection(list);
    System.out.println(intersection); // works fine
    list.add(intersection);
    DLRConceptIntersection intersection2 = new DLRConceptIntersection(list);
    System.out.println(intersection2); //loop never ends!
}
```

Is a correct approach to fix this problem?

Comment: You have an intersection that includes itself. What do you *want* it to print?

Comment: Are you aware that your `list` is being shared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular reference :

```
DLRConceptIntersection intersection = new DLRConceptIntersection(list);
list.add(intersection);
```

This causes the `intersection`'s List to contain a reference to the same instance referred by `intersection`, which is why `toString()` run into infinite recursion.

I'm assuming you didn't intend `intersection` and `intersection2` to share the same `List`.

You can avoid it if you create a copy of the `List` in the `DLRConceptIntersection` constructor:

```
public ConceptIntersection(List<Concept> l) throws Exception {
    if(l.size()>1) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(l);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Intersection needs at least two concepts!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's worked for me! I didn't intend intersection and intersection2 to share the same List, so that's why the loop never ended. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with the same code about the complement of a concept: public ComplementOfConcept(Concept c) {
  this.concept = c;
 }
Since Concept is an abstract class, is it possible do the same like with List?